# clearing datatable custom search when browser or tab is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a datatable with a custom search filter.

When a user selects various search parameters on a form from the Home screen and submits, it takes you to a Header screen which then loads the datatable based on the parameters selected from the previous screen.

The user can then narrow down their search by using the custom filter.

From the datatable, they can click on a record which takes them to another screen (called Lane) and loads some more information.

When they click to go back to the Header screen, the original values they entered in the custom filter has been retained.

When they click to go back to the Home screen, the values they entered into the custom filter is removed.

The problem I am having is when the user enters a search in the custom filter, and then happens to close the browser.

When they log back in, select new parameters from the Home screen and submit, the original value they entered in the custom filter has been retained...this is a problem.

Here is the HTML custom filter:

```
 <input type="search" id="searchFilterHeader" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' />
```

As you will notice, I have a function called 'saveValue()'.

Here is the JavaScript functions 'saveValue' and get 'getSavedValue':

```
document.getElementById("searchFilterHeader").value = getSavedValue("searchFilterHeader"); 

function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.id;  
  var val = e.value; 
  localStorage.setItem(id, val);
}

function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return "";
  }
return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
```

Using the above, as stated above, I can retain the values of the custom search when they navigate back to the Header screen from the Lane screen.

I manually clear out the custom filter when they navigate back to the Home screen from the Header screen using the following:

```
$('#homeLink').on('click', function() {
    $('#searchFilterHeader').val("");
    $('#searchFilterHeader').keyup().val("");
});
```

The problem occurs when they close the browser and then log back in to conduct another search - the custom filter is retaining their last narrowed search.

Is there a way I can clear the filters when the browser is closed?

How can I make this work?